# error: no type or protocol named 'UIAlertViewDelegate'

Tags: swift, uialertviewdelegate, alipay

Using swift 2.0 Xcode 7.1.
And I am going to use an essential 3rd party library which is written in Objective-C. Also it's using `UIAlertViewDelegate` and this error occurs when I am trying to import it from the bridging header file.
Can you guys give me some advice to make it work?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated on `iOS9`. You should use `UIAlertController`.

Comment: @longpham I know that. But the sdk is out of my control, I don't know what will happen if I remove the `<UIALertViewDelegate>` in the header of file.

Comment: I don't know why you need to import the `UIAlertViewDelegate` to `Bridge header file`?.

Comment: @longpham It's the 3rd party library using `UIAlertViewDelegate`, I have to use the library to extend my app's functionality.

Comment: What is the 3rd you're using? If you want to extends it. You need to refactor the 3rd api which using deprecated api.

Comment: @longpham I can only see the header files in the framework. AND I have no access to the sources files.

Comment: Only way for this case is upgrade `3rd framework` for latest `iOS9`. If framework is no longer supported. You must handle the api that has deprecated. Thanks.

Comment: @longpham OK, thanks.